# Салат из пекинской (,) или китайской (,) капусты - нужны ли здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Не могу найти соответствующего правила. Имеется в виду не выбор из двух видов, а конкретизация. Пекинская - синоним китайской.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второе определение является пояснительным и обособляется:

**Салат из пекинской, или китайской, капусты.**

Розенталь: [§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)

2. Пояснительные члены предложения могут присоединяться союзом **или** (‘то есть’): Кольчатый тюлень, или нерпа, относится к числу ластоногих (Арсеньев).